# Python - Column concatenation based on length of data inside the column

Tags: python, concatenation, multiple-columns, string-length

Need help on column concatenation based on length size .

Column3= df["column1"] + "_" + df["column2"]

data = {'column1':['af28912368', 'Nan', '234671', 'asr61239'],
'column2':[701, Nan, 761, 312]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df :

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| af28912368 | 701 |
| NaN | Nan |
| 234671 | 761 |
| asr61239 | 312 |

If length of the data in column1 is greater than 8 , then need to Insert last 8 symbols of column1
If length of the data in column1 <8 & >0 , Insert value of df['column1'] + (8-Len(df['column1'])) of Blank Spaces
If NaN on Column1 , Column3 can remain as NaN

expected result as shown on column3

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aa289123sf | 701 | 289123sf_701 |
| NaN | 723 | Nan |
| 234671 | 761 | 234671 _761 |
| asr61239 | 312 | asr61239_312 |

I tried this :

df["column3"] = df["column1"].str[-8:] + '_' + df["column2"].astype(str)
But not working with different length size of df["column1"] . Please help on this one.

Comment: Please format your code with backticks for single lines or triple backticks for multi-line code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're first row column1 value keeps changing so I'm assuming this is a typo and not part of the exercise

this script worked for me:

```py
───────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: test-so.py
───────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ import pandas as pd
   2   │ from pprint import pprint
   3   │
   4   │ data = {'column1':['af28912368', None, '234671', 'asr61239'], 'column2':[701, None, 761, 312]}
   5   │ df = pd.DataFrame(data)
   6   │
   7   │ def funk(col1,col2):
   8   │     try:
   9   │         tmp = len(col1)
  10   │         if tmp > 8:
  11   │             return col1[:8] +'_'+ str(int(col2))
  12   │         elif tmp <= 8 and tmp > 0:
  13   │             return (int(tmp % 8))*' ' + col1 +'_'+ str(int(col2))
  14   │         else:
  15   │             return None
  16   │     except TypeError as e:
  17   │         return None
  18   │
  19   │ def main():
  20   │     df['column3'] = df.apply(lambda row: funk(row['column1'],row['column2']),axis=1)
  21   │     pprint(df)
  22   │
  23   │ if __name__ == '__main__':
  24   │     main()
```

**from command line:**

```bash
python test-so.py
```

**yields:**

[image: pic]

Comment: This condition got missed . 
How to include this one :

If length of the data in column1 is <8 & >0 , Insert value of df['column1'] + (8-Len(df['column1'])) of Blank Spaces

Comment: As per your script output: concatenation of 234671 & 761 is 234671_761

But i am expecting as "234671  _761" (before underscore 2 blank spaces got added , because the length of the data in row 3 is 6.  So included 2 blank space 8-6 = 2

Comment: Sorry, It is on Row 2

Comment: added conditional. you can use the modulo operator to get the remainder from 8

Comment: Yes . Now Trying to fix the error occurred during the execution. 

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: oops, should be inside the try/except

Comment: @SathishKumar please accept this answer if it satisfies your question